# Trying to Print List: Getting Empty

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
>>> f=open('list.txt')
>>> print list(f)
['bird\n', 'cat\n', 'cat\n', 'cat\n', 'tree']
>>> mylist=list(f)
>>> print mylist
[]   
>>> print list(f)
[]
```

Why is the list empty??? Earlier in the code it shows the list is the correct list. Further, why it the first command "print mylist" showing an empty list? I had previously set mylist=list(f). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you already read the whole file. Once you have read a file, the file pointer has been moved to the end and no more data will be 'found' beyond that point.

Re-open the file or seek back to the start:

```
f.seek(0)
```

Note that your first line is `print list(f)`; this exhausted the file iterator (moved the file pointer to the end of te file).

Your next statement is then `mylist=list(f)`, which tries to read from `f` *again*. The file pointer is still at the end of the file, no data is returned when reading and an empty list is created.